# Ical import event not working event my ical file has no error

Tags: icalendar

I want to import my ical event to google calender, but it is not working, It says 0 events imported, I checked with ical validator, it says no issue with the ical file, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue, here is my ical data

`BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/New_York
BEGIN:STANDARD
LOCATION:Ponton 2 Quilles |Â Demi-JournÃ©e (Avant-midi)
DESCRIPTION:Ponton 2 Quilles |Â Demi-JournÃ©e (Avant-midi)
DTSTART:20190619T070000Z
DTEND:20190619T120000Z
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
SUMMARY:Ponton 2 Quilles |Â Demi-JournÃ©e (Avant-midi)
URL:https://fassettmarine.com
DTSTAMP:20190619T070000Z
UID:5cf75576d13b6
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:STANDARD
LOCATION:Test Product For Tako
DESCRIPTION:Test Product For Tako
DTSTART:20190517T160607Z
DTEND:20190518T160611Z
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
SUMMARY:Test Product For Tako
URL:https://fassettmarine.com
DTSTAMP:20190517T160607Z
UID:5cf75576d13b1
END:STANDARD
END:VCALENDAR`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Sunny! You've tried other things to fix the problem, right? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your properties are in random order and missing the BEGIN:VEVENT/END:VEVENT.

iCalendar is following a fixed structure with components as containers for properties (and potentially other components). See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6

So you should have something like:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
... VCALENDAR properties go here
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
... VTIMEZONE properties go here
BEGIN:STANDARD
... STANDARD properties go here
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
...
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
... VEVENT properties go here
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

As a matter of fact, since your event seem to be using zulu time, you can even skip the whole VTIMEZONE/STANDARD and simply go for

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
... VCALENDAR properties go here
BEGIN:VEVENT
... VEVENT properties go here
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```